# Electric field due to a ring/disk at a point straight above a hypothetical point on the axis of ring/disk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Its easy to find the electric field due to a uniformly charged ring or disc at a point on the axis of ring/disc. But I cant figure out a way to find the electric field or even potential at a point at height z above or below the axis of charged ring/disc. Please help me with this.

[image]

We have to find electric field at point O(which is directly above an axial hypothetical point P)

I suspect gauss's law is to be used here somehow.

Comment: Have you tried approaches that didn't work, or brought you to a point where you could go no further?

Comment: @garyp yes i tried finding field at O by gauss law by taking a imaginary cylinder at that point but I did not know how to proceed further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106277/discussion-between-shashank-and-fakemod).

Comment: [Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12807/179151) about the closing of this question.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.